# change url dynamically in dropzone

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

i have a [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) container in a modal. I want to access the same modal on the same page from 15 - 20 links to upload different types of documents (identified by `data-doctype`).

i need to change the url for every doctype and somehow i am not able to get around it. I have checked this [link](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Set-URL-dynamically), but its not what i am looking for. The dropzone container is pretty trivial (in the modal body):

```
<div id="docUpload" class="dropzone">
     <div class="dz-default dz-message">
          Click to select document to upload 
      </div>
</div>
```

this is how i call the modal

```
<a data-target="#identityModal" data-toggle="modal" data-doctype="dl" class="fa fa-paperclip docLink"></a>
<a data-target="#identityModal" data-toggle="modal" data-doctype="voter" class="fa fa-paperclip docLink"></a>
```

this is how i am initializing the dropzone

```
$(document).on("click", ".docLink", function () {

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#docUpload", {
        url: "../hn_SimpeFileUploader.ashx?doctype=" + $(this).data('doctype'),
        maxFiles: 2,
        addRemoveLinks: false,
        success: function (file, response) {
            var imgName = response;
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
        },
        error: function (file, response) {
            file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
        }
    });
});
```

I need to reset the url with the doctype query parameter as per the clicked link.

the URL is not getting updated and i get "dropzone already attached" error. Please note with this code, the documents are getting uploaded properly. its just that the url is not getting updated and all docs are getting uploaded in same folder.

Comment: i think this would be easier to accomplish on server side.

Answer (score 0):

i could solve the issue by doing the following:

- declare a global variable `myDropzone`
- on page load initialize `myDropzone` with a default url
- on modal load set the url parameter

works pretty well.